# Skill could be “Obtained” or "Trained"?

Tags: meaning

Background: I have several skills like programming, data analysis, etc., which were learned when I was a graduate student, and I was a graduate student for 3 years, so how should I say like this:

```
...all these skills were obtained after almost three years' post-graduate training...
```

Comment: "Developed during" would be better than "obtained after".

Comment: "developed" means "from know nothing to known" or "from primary to premium"?

Comment: "Develop" = "to improve|advance by deliberate effort over a period of time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Skill should be obtained** " is a correct usage.
skill is an ability that has been acquired by training